# How to code Universal Exit in an Indicator in Pine Script v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In my strategy I wanted to initiate trades 10 minutes once the exchange opens and close all open positions (Universal Exit) 10 minutes before the exchange closes.
My question is: If I want to convert this strategy into an Indicator, how can I code it to get the same result?
Thanks in advance.

```
//@version=5
strategy("EMAs Strategy", overlay = true, 
calc_on_every_tick=true, process_orders_on_close = 
true)

session_time = input.session("0925-1520", 
"Session")
is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, 
session_time)
longEntryCondition = (is_in_session) and 
(ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close))
longCloseCondition = (is_in_session) and ((ta.crossunder(close,ema9Close)) or (rsiClose >= 80))
if (longEntryCondition)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (longCloseCondition)
strategy.close("Long")

shortEntryCondition = (is_in_session) and 
(ta.crossunder(ema10Close , ema20Close))
shortCloseCondition = (is_in_session) and ((ta.crossover(close,ema9Close)) or (rsiClose <= 20))

if (shortEntryCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
if (shortCloseCondition)
    strategy.close("Short")   


if not is_in_session
    strategy.close_all(comment = 'Trading session ended, all positions closed.')
```

Written codes for indicator alerts. Do change them if requires.

```
alertcondition(longEntryCondition, title = 
"Long", message = "Long")
alertcondition(longCloseCondition, title = 
"Long Exit", message = "Long Exit")
alertcondition(shortEntryCondition, title = 
"Short", message = "Short")
alertcondition(shortCloseCondition, title = 
"Short Exit", message = "Short Exit")
```

Comment: It depends on how you code your indicator. Can you share an example?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there. Also, please share your complete code.

Comment: Did as you asked for.

Comment: Well, that's a strategy. Where is your indicator code?

Comment: Please don't add your code as a comment. You can always edit your question.

Comment: I almost completed the conversion. A part of the strategy is left. Can you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76248196/can-anybody-please-help-to-to-convert-the-following-pine-script-strategy-codes-i